# SQLite how to limit the number of records

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt, count, triggers

I want to limit the number of records in my SQLite table to for example 100 records, and then when I INSERT the 101th record, the first record (the oldest) be removed from the table. In other word, I want to prevent the table from growing more than 100 records and always have the last 100 records. Is there any setting or query with SQLite or should I handle it manually?
thanks in advance

Comment: You probably need to handle that manually.

Comment: There's no SQL query that allows you to do that. You can have an SQL query which retrieves the latest 100 records, but the table would still store more. You would need to write a function in C++ that deletes the earliest entry when adding an entry if the new entry exceeds 100 rows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with a trigger.

Say that your table is this:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  name TEXT, 
  inserted_at TEXT DEFAULT (strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', 'now'))
);
```

In the column `inserted_at` you will have the timestamp of the insertion of each row.
This is not necessary if you declared the column `id` as:

```
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

because in this case you could identify the 1st inserted row by the minimum value of the `id`.

Now create this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER keep_100_rows AFTER INSERT ON tablename
  WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename) > 100 
  BEGIN
    DELETE FROM tablename
    WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM tablename ORDER BY inserted_at, id LIMIT 1);
    -- or if you define id as AUTOINCREMENT
    -- WHERE id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM tablename);
  END;
END;
```

Every time that you insert a new row, the trigger will check if the table has more than 100 rows and if it does it will delete the 1st inserted row.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0d32dab2497ed9645bdc03980577295d) (for max 3 rows).